# Question on the music production of Atreides Anthem

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, film-sound-design, plug-ins, cinema

*The soundtrack [1] presents a sort of a anthem.*

**Concerning the music production of [1]:** there is a moment in this music that is really something; very powerful, yet gentle. This moment starts at 6:54 min and ends at 7:18 min. Are there any plugins available in the market that can reproduce this singing (specially the "he humm" at 7:04-7:11 min)?

---

[1]

Comment: There's Vocaloid and the like, but you'd be hard pressed to match the subtle inflections and dynamics of a real vocalist with it.  There's a real performance happening in the recording you posted; always a challenge to make a computer do something as good.

Comment: Also, if you just like ambient vocal sounds, check out Exhale from the company Output.  Nice sound design in it for sure.

Comment: Sounds like a flanger or phaser + some delay